# Dijkstra's Algorithm , C++, Priority Queue, Adjacency List

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, graph, queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

struct Vertices {
    int vertex;
    int weight;
    Vertices(int v, int w) : vertex(v), weight(w) { };
    Vertices() { }
};

class CompareGreater {
    public:
        bool const operator()(Vertices &nodeX, Vertices &nodeY) {
            return (nodeX.weight > nodeY.weight) ;
        }
};

vector< list<Vertices> > adj;
vector<int> weights;
priority_queue<Vertices, vector<Vertices>, CompareGreater> Q;

int nrVertices, nrEdges;


void Dijkstra(Vertices);


void makeGraph() {

    ifstream myFile;

    myFile.open("graph.txt");


    myFile >> nrVertices >> nrEdges;

    adj.resize(nrVertices+1);


    int nodeX, nodeY, weight;


    for (int i = 1; i <= nrVertices; ++i) {
        weights.push_back(INT_MAX);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= nrEdges; ++i) {
        myFile >> nodeX >> nodeY >> weight;
        adj[nodeX].push_back(Vertices(nodeY, weight));
    }
}

void printPath()
{
    for (vector<int>::iterator itr = weights.begin()+1; itr != weights.end(); ++itr) {
        cout <<  (*itr) << " "<<endl;
    }

}

void Dijkstra(Vertices startNode) {
    Vertices currVertex;

    weights[startNode.vertex] = 0;
    Q.push(startNode);

    while (!Q.empty()) {
        currVertex = Q.top();
        Q.pop();

        cout<<"Removed "<<&currVertex<<"from heap"<<endl;

        if (currVertex.weight <= weights[currVertex.vertex]) {
            for (list<Vertices>::iterator it = adj[currVertex.vertex].begin(); it != adj[currVertex.vertex].end(); ++it)
            {
                if (weights[it->vertex] > weights[currVertex.vertex] + it->weight) {
                    weights[it->vertex] = weights[currVertex.vertex] + it->weight;
                    Q.push(Vertices((it->vertex), weights[it->vertex]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    makeGraph();
    Dijkstra(Vertices(1, 0));
    printPath();

    return 0;
}
```

So this is my code to implement Dijkstra's algorithm with an adjacency list. With input:

```
7
2
2  2
4  1
2
4  3
5  10
2
1  4
6  5
4
3  2
5  2
6  8
7  4
1
7  6
0
1
6  1
```

This means that there exists 7 vertices in order from vertex 1 to 7. Vertex 1 has 2 edges, one to vertex 2 with weight 2, the second to vertex 4 with weight 1. Vertex 2 has 2 edges, the first to vertex 4 with weight 3, the second to vertex 5 with weight 10. Vertex 3 has 2 edges, the first to vertex 1 with weight 4, the second to vertex 6 with weight 5. And so forth.

However, it print out this:

```
Removed 0xbfb9d7a8from heap
Removed 0xbfb9d7a8from heap
0 
4 
2147483647 
2147483647 
2147483647 
2147483647
```

When I need it to print out this:

```
V1: V2, 2; V4, 1
V2: v4, 3; V5, 10
V3: V1, 4; V6, 5
V4: V3, 2; V5, 2; V6, 8; V7, 4
V5: V7, 6
V6:
V7: V6, 1
Removed minimum 1 from heap
Print heap: V2, d=inf V4., d=inf v3, d= inf v7, d=inf v5......
```

Please help!!!!!

Comment: Did you check all of the alreadiy existing Q$A about this topic here? ...

Comment: Your problem isn't with the algorithm as much as it is a misunderstanding of [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream). You're telling `cout` to output the address of a pointer. What did you expect it to do, make coffee? If you don't want it to output a pointer value don't pass it a pointer value.

Comment: I get the pointer part. That was just a stupid mistake. But how do I output the current vertex that the algorithm is looking at? @CaptainObvlious ?

Comment: Also, any idea why it doesn't loop around? @CaptainObvlious

Comment: Tried following the code flow using a debugger?

Comment: makeGraph() does not align with your file format for starters. First make sure you are reading in all of the data into the correct structures, then worry about the rest of the code. Print out your data structures at the end of makeGraph() or step through it in a debugger. Without correct data to begin with there's nothing the rest of your code can do to get the right answer.